# Blazor Server App integrated with Azure AD: Public/Anonymous pages not working

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm running a .net 6 core blazor server app.  Here's the situation.  Originally the whole site was to be protected using Azure Ad SSO.  Then arose a requirement to have some pages be publicly available.  I posted all the code examples in another forum so hopefully its okay to just link over to there so I don't have to type up the whole situation again - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45711

I followed an example I found online.  My public razor page will display, but if you look at the developer tools there are a few errors related to the Azure ad sso stuff.  Any clickable element on the razor page doesn't work because of the console errors. If I remove the azure ad sso code block from my Program.cs file, my public page runs just fine.

I tried declaring my 'Public' directory in my solution using  options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Public") in my Program.cs file but that didn't do anything.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting CORS error in the console ? if Yes, have you tried using adding CORS poilcy. eg. services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});

Comment: I just tried adding that, but it didn't change anything.  Same exact result as before.

Comment: Someone has had to come across this issue before.  Is there anyway to resolve this?